# What is the purpose of GStack.HostToNetwork in Indy?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

I saw that Indy, by default, coverts data which must be sent in some "network format", and when is received, is converted back. What is the point of doing this ? Between the `Write` and the `Read` from the socket no one uses those values that only "I" know what they means. So, what does it matter the bit order ? I have my own TCP Server-Client protocol and I write drectly to a temporary buffer the values of the commands and other stuff I send. I want to know if it makes sense to complicate my protocol with those conversions ?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking) for some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I saw that Indy, by default, coverts data which must be sent in some "network format", and when is received, is converted back. What is the point of doing this ?

Not all platforms use the same endian for ordering the bytes in a multi-byte integer.  Some platforms are little-endian, some are big-endian.  To facilitate sharing of integers across platforms, "Network Byte Order" is standardized as big-endian.  Thus, `HostToNetwork()` will convert a multi-byte integer from the calling platform's native endian to big-endian, and `NetworkToHost()` will convert a multi-byte integer from big-endian to the calling platform's native endian.

> Between the Write and the Read from the socket no one uses those values that only "I" know what they means. So, what does it matter the bit order ?

If you are writing both the sender and the receiver, then of course you can use whatever endian you want.  But it is *customary* to always use only big-endian when transmitting integers over a network connection.  Maybe someday, you or someone else will write a different sender/receiver for your system, maybe even on another platform.  So if you use a standardized endian for your integers, you won't have to worry about interoperability issues later on.

> I have my own TCP Server-Client protocol and I write drectly to a temporary buffer the values of the commands and other stuff I send.

That will, of course, only work if the sender and the receiver represent integers in memory using the same endian.

> I want to know if it makes sense to complicate my protocol with those conversions ?

Doing endian conversions does not complicate anything, but it does safe-guard it.